How do you decrypt an f2fs partition?
I have got an encrypted f2fs image, I know the password, I'm able to mount it via sudo mount -t f2fs mmcblk0p64.img /mnt/mmcblk0p64 so it doesn't appear broken or anything, and f2fscrypt recognizes the policy
f2fscrypt get_policy /mnt/mmcblk0p64/data                                     
/mnt/mmcblk0p64/data: 17532673d8ab1f9f

however
fsck.f2fs -f mmcblk0p64.img
Info: Force to fix corruption
Info: MKFS version
  "4.9.206-perf+"
Info: FSCK version
  from "4.9.206-perf+"
    to "Linux version 6.5.7-060507-generic (kernel@sita) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3) 13.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.41) #202310102154 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Oct 10 22:00:30 UTC 2023"
Info: superblock features = 481 :  encrypt verity quota_ino
Info: superblock encrypt level = 0, salt = 1a9ecca697dd4d1b9eb0d41a55754d41
Info: Segments per section = 1
Info: Sections per zone = 1
Info: total FS sectors = 104939480 (51239 MB)
Info: CKPT version = 9d277d6
Info: checkpoint state = 44 :  crc compacted_summary sudden-power-off

prints this salt, and when trying to use it to add a key like this:
f2fscrypt add_key -S 1a9ecca697dd4d1b9eb0d41a55754d41
Invalid salt: 1a9ecca697dd4d1b9eb0d41a55754d41

it fails. Is this the wrong salt, where do I get the salt for this purpose?
The img comes from a broken android device, running kernel 4.9.206-perf+
f2fs-tools version f2fs-tools/mantic,now 1.16.0-1
Using twrp is not an option, it fails to decrypt it via the shell and the screen is broken. I need to be able to decrypt it on my computer.

The salt can be used and printed using f2fscrypt add_key -v -S /mnt/mmcblk0p64. It's important that the -v is in front of the -S.
In this case, I'm getting 1a9ecca6-97dd-4d1b-9eb0-d41a55754d41 as salt. However, this salt doesn't seem to work. Is there some sort of master key that is decrypted by android first?

Looks like I'm out of luck. "The decryption is related to hardware so only the device which creates these keys are able to decrypt them." https://xdaforums.com/t/mate-9-how-to-retrieve-encrypted-files-from-a-broken-system-userdata-partition.3894561/
